# Writing tests with local dynamodb using mocha

Tags: mocha.js, amazon-dynamodb, chai

I am using Dynamodb for an api service I am writing. I started writing tests and I found that there is no command(or query) which destroys all the "items" in a table. I am using vogels to access dynamodb.

I usually clean the table before every test. How do I do that given that there is no single command( or query) that deletes all the items in a table?

If I delete each item one by one the tests start executing before all the items get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The CRUD operation is atomic in DynamoDB. There is no API available to delete all the items in the DynamoDB table.

**Solution 1:**

The best recommended solution is to delete the table and recreate it.

**Solution 2:**

Use batchWriteItem with DeleteRequest for deleting multiple items in one go. The maximum number of requests on batch write is 25 items.

**Wait for:-**

After executing the delete table, please wait until the resource is not available. Similarly, after executing the create table, you need to wait until the resource is available.

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
dynamodb.waitFor('tableNotExists', params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

> Waits for the tableNotExists state by periodically calling the
>   underlying DynamoDB.describeTable() operation every 20 seconds (at
>   most 25 times).

Comment: 1.I tried the first one. The deletion is happening but the recreation is not happening in time. Before table gets recreated the tests are being run (and we have to clean the db before every test). Any suggestion on that?

2. Even if I use the batchWriteItem API I have to make two calls. One to get the list of items and the other to delete it. The problem again would be that the tests would run before the deletion happens. 

How did you make it work for you?

Comment: Updated my answer with wait for resource. It has both flavors i.e. tableNotExists and tableExists.